# how to set NSDictionary without Keys

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i have two arrays stored in dictionary:

```
array1=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:a,b,c,d,e, nil];
array2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:1,2,3, nil];
 NSDictionary * dic=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:array1 forKeys:array2];
```

if i run i am getting error as:

```
-[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (1)'
```

now i want to set dictionary only for a,b,c with keys: 1,2,3.

were as the arrays can't be edited

how can i do that

Comment: Provide equal number of objects to both the arrays.

Comment: hmmm. i cant control the arrays that's the problem

Comment: A dictionary without keys is called an array.

Comment: You want to set a key for the whole array or for each and every object of array?

Comment: set key for whole array,!,, how to do that

Comment: Well, the short answer is that you can't store an object in a dictionary without a key; thats the purpose of a dictionary - to recall something with a known key value. If you dont NEED a key, then what you're looking at is an Array, as suggested earlier.

Comment: You need only for a,b,c ? what about d and e? let 'em go waste?

Comment: Madhu as AKV said i need only a,b,c

Comment: @PradeepKumar : `how to set NSDictionary without Keys` Just now I answered dictionary need NO-NIL for keys and values, in other question. Please remember all these concepts. :)

Comment: @PradeepKumar, cool :) In that case the answers provided below should work out for you. Cheers!

Comment: i cant remove d,e from array

Answer (score 2):

It does not make sense to add keys for nil values.

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, MIN(array1.count, array2.count));
NSDictionary * dic=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:[array1 subarrayWithRange:range]
                                                forKeys:[array2 subarrayWithRange:range]];
```

Comment: Thanks. It needs still some improvements. Checking for zero length for example.

Answer (score 1):

Use as :

```
array1=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:a,b,c,d,e, nil];
array2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:1,2,3, nil];
// NSDictionary * dic=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:array1 forKeys:array2];

NSMutableDictionary * dic=[NSMutableDictionary new];
for(int i=0 ; i< array2.count ; i++ ){
   [dic setObject:array1[i] forKey:array2[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSMutableArray to work with the first array
remove d & e from it

Comment: Got what you mean now. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

A single key for the whole array is simple to set:

```
NSDictionary * dic=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:array1 forKeys:@"Array"];
```

And if you want to add a key to each of the object in array, it goes like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
int key = 1;
for (NSString *str in array1) {
    [dict setObject:str forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",key]];
    key++;
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: arrays can't be edited am getting that from service , as i mentioned in question

Comment: Why use an NSDictionnary if you have the same key?
And a key should be unique.

Comment: I m here using incremented value of key in the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

From the Doc:

Neither a key nor a value can be nil; if you need to represent a null value in a dictionary, you should use NSNull.